# Website for Indirectly downloading a webpage?

Tags: web-apps, download-manager

There are many websites (e.g. [this one](https://mp3-convert.org/youtube-to-mp3/)) which can, given the URL of a youtube video provided by a user, download the audio or video, convert them into .mp3 or .mp4 format, and then allow the user or anyone to download the .mp3 or .mp4 file.

Is there a web application, where given an URL of a webpage provided by a user, it can either download the webpage and allow the user or anyone to download the webpage from it, without the user directly access the URL of the webpage? The downloaded webpage can be

- either an archive file consisting of .html and *_files folder like those downloaded by  a web browser,
- or a converted document file such as .pdf.

I am more interested in websites that can perform downloading on demand, similarly to those for downloading youtube videos or audios, than those (such as web search engines) that cache webpages beforehand. I can't access unrestricted search engines directly.